# Unable to create SMS config: Host name of server URL is not FQD in openam

Tags: openam

I am trying to setup fresh instance of OpenAM. I am getting “Invalid Host Name” error at the last of the configuration. I am trying to integrate it with my existing OpenDJ instance. I have set my hostname properly as FQDN. It is set in /etc/hosts and /etc/sysconfig. I also verified it with hostname cmd and it is perfectly matching. I am trying to deploy OpenAM 13.

Comment: Which OpenAM instance URL are you using?

Comment: i am try with this URL..  http://localhost:8080/openam

Comment: By default OpenAM 13 uses domain-cookies, so you can not use 'localhost' but you need to use some real FQDN which you resolve in your /etc/hosts file.